# Что будет если достигло количество циклов перезаписи 10.000 тыс. что будет с SSD?

Tags: linux, windows, ssd, диск

"Главная проблема SSD-накопителей – это ограниченное количество циклов перезаписи, от 10 000 в недорогих моделях SSD до 100 000 циклов в SSD с более дорогостоящим типом памяти."

Что будет если достигло количество циклов перезаписи 10.000 тыс. что будет с SSD?

Comment: как повезет. Скорее всего будет ещё работать. Потом будет доступен только на чтение, а потом и читаться не будет.

Comment: @KoVadim, а как узнать сколько уже было циклов перезаписи?

Comment: @KoVadim, т.е. вообще работать не будет. не запустится даже нельзя выкачать файлы будет?

Comment: @olgabulanovva посмотреть состояние диска в S.M.A.R.T, для этого есть множество программ (CrystalDiskInfo и подобные)

Comment: @KoVadim, а где в CrystalDiskInfo смотреть сколько было перезаписей?

Comment: 10000 - это условное количество, до которого скорее всего оно будет работать нормально. CrystalDiskInfo  я последний раз запускал много лет назад и понятия не имею, где это там смотреть. А почему возник такой вопрос? в большинстве случаев в домашних условиях тяжело достичь такого. Но если торренты не выключать и файлы туда-сюда ганять, то да, можно.

Comment: сложность в том, что 10 тысяч - это не число записей в диск, а число записей в отдельный блок. Нужно искать тот блок, который чаще остальных перезаписывается. Крутые драйверы  SSD перемещают самые перезаписываемые блоки (такие как суперблок файловой системы или каталог `/tmp`) по диску. Поэтому на ваш вопрос нет однозначного ответа.

Comment: @Pak Uula, а сколько этих блоков может быть? на весь ssd, нужно ли парится по этому поводу? что закончится

Comment: @KoVadim, торренты не используется мной вообще как и ком.игры

Comment: Кто поставил минус?

Comment: есть тут анонимные минусаторы-вахтеры. они ставят молча и уходят. Подозреваю, что могут за отсутствующую запятую поставить или просто вопрос не поняли (ибо просто не могут)

Comment: у меня есть ноут, на котором я пересобирал генту и ничего уже лет 6 работает и проблем нет. Правда там стоит от самсунга ссд с приставкой pro.

Comment: Если вопрос задан с практической точки зрения, то беспокоится по этому поводу не нужно. Таких значений в домашних условиях  достичь невозможно. Вы быстрее купите новый компьютер, чем у вас износятся ячейки в диске. А ссд если и сломается, то скорее всего из-за контроллера, а не износа.

Comment: @Эникейщик, а этот контроллер ломается. по каким причинам(наиболее часто)

Comment: @olgabulanovva я согласен с Эникейщиком. В условиях домашнего использования добиться 10 тысяч записей в отдельный блок - нереально. Это ограничение имеет смысл для серверных приложений, в которых создаётся множество временных файлов в отдельных папках. Поэтому пользуйтесь спокойно SSD. Тем не мене, бэкап время от времени делать стоит )))

Comment: Pak Uula, по каким наиболее частым причинам SSD летят... ломаются.?

Comment: ни разу не видел сломанный SSD )))
Какой сценарий использования вы предполагаете - домашний, вычисления или веб-сервер?

Comment: Pak Uula, домашний.

Comment: Берите SSD известной компании - Intel, Adata, Kingston, Samsung -  и не переживайте. Но рабочие файлы держите в облаке )) У меня SSD от Интела, но рабочая папка отмаплена на Yandex.Disk

Comment: SSD как и любая другая электроника может выйти из строя из за того что вам просто не повезло. может брак заводской, может скачек напряжения, или высокоэнергетическая частица из космоса попала неудачно